# How do I fix copy/paste in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

At the beginning of this week, I noticed that I can no longer properly copy and paste into or out of a Google Document. I find that if I highlight more than one paragraph and press Edit / Copy or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, it will not copy. Even when I select only one paragraph, it still will not copy.

The only way I can get it to copy is when I leave off the first character in the paragraph, the last character in the paragraph, or both. Then I have to copy paragraph-by-paragraph out of the Google Doc.

I've tried this on two different machines, both running Firefox. Does this happen for anyone else, and if so do you have a fix?

Comment: Does this happen in other web pages, esp. in rich text fields like gmail message composition? Does it happen in other browsers? If you clear the browser's cache and site-specific data then restart the browser, does that fix it?

Comment: I haven't had it happen yet today. If it does, I'll try each of these.

Comment: Maybe it's related with non-visible characters in that paragraph? I've been using Google docs really heavily for the past few days and haven't seen this at all.

Comment: So I noticed an error a day or two ago when I copy from Google Documents, it says, `Error loading fonts...`, and a "Learn More" link, but it always disappears before I can click it.

Comment: I found a temporary solution where if I copied and pasted from/to the Google Doc, I would then be able to paste elsewhere. ... But now I can no longer paste in Google Docs! If I try to use Edit / Paste, it gives me the "action is no longer available" message.

Comment: Oh man, were we even on Australis in 2014? It must be fixed since I used Google Docs just about every day and can't remember the last time I dealt with this issue. Suggested fix: upgrade to Firefox Quantum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to this issue: [Cut and paste function does not work on Google docs? (Mozilla Support)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1196485) You can try by setting "dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled" to true in "about:config" (you can access it by putting about:config in the location bar of Firefox).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any solution is better than no solution, thanks!