# Control+C, Control+X, and Control+V stopped working in Google docs

Tags: google-docs, firefox, linux

To protect the clipboard for security reasons, one uses `control`+`c`, `control`+`x`, and `control`+`v` to copy, cut, and paste in Google docs, respectively. *Recently, this stopped working for me.*

- I'm running Mozilla Firefox 108.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
- I cannot copy, cut, or paste *at all*. This makes my issue different from previous reports, which indicate that they can copy/paste subsets of text, or only copy/paste within the document, or only copy/paste to/from the address bar, etc.
- On Linux, you can usually copy/paste text by highlighting it, and pasting by clicking with the centre mouse button, this is also not working.
- I have completely disabled all extensions at the same time, and the behaviour is unchanged.

Any ideas?

This may or may not be the same issue as [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/65771/254954). However, until more information is provided there, we should assume the issue I'm experiencing is not the same bug.

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40147/88163 from 2013, related from [su] [Is there a simple method to copy an image from Google Docs to the local clipboard?](https://superuser.com/q/413115/152004)

Comment: From [ubuntu.se] [Can't paste text into Google Docs in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/q/999464/1163497)

Comment: Third link seems to have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Rubén's third [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999464/cant-paste-text-into-google-docs-in-firefox)

It seems like this fixed it:

Go to the "page" `about:config`; Search for the property `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` and set it to true.